# Apache Ignite - time series forecasting

Tags: ignite

I'm pretty new to Apache Ignite

I need to make some forecasting analysis

Basically I can collect data in Ignite in real time. Ignite will store data in its own caches

Now I need to make some forecasting showing me the distribution of data in the next X months/years by starting from observed and collected data.

As far as I know, this kind of forecasting can be realized by time series forecasting. In Ignite I see no time series based algorithm. Am I right?

If I'm correct I may use or tensor flow or Deep Java Library. But in this case what I don't understand is: where should I use these libraries? Inside my thick client microservice or should I write an Ignite plugin in order to use the scalability feature provided by Ignite?

Thank you

Angelo